# Node - "mkdir /var/log/some_dir" Permission Denied

Tags: node.js

I am creating a node.js persistent logger.
I want to create a directory for logging under /var/log and get the permission denied, because I am running under my user.

My question is, when creating this directory in node what is the generally accepted approach? Should I be doing a sudo command and having the user putting in their password if the dir needs to be created?

Comment: To clarify, I run the mkdir with an exec command that doesn't create the directory and I want to know if I should try to run that same exec command with sudo and somehow get them to enter their password or if their is another way to achieve this sort of thing that I'm missing.

Comment: I see stuff like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt but I'd like to avoid using a library for this if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to create a directory under `/var/log` and assign permissions to yourself for that, as a one-off sudo that could perhaps also be in your setup instructions. it's not great or at all secure to have to use sudo before running commands, but it's okay for setting up.

Once the permissions are configured you should be fine. Essentially try not running the app as root. Also consider if your logs do in fact need to be in that location. Just some suggestions.

Comment: I did think about putting this directory under the user's home directory and after your answer I think this is actually a good idea. That way logging can be contained within whatever user account runs an application. And the permission issue is moot now.